# How to OverRide some of the methods of VideoView of android

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any Listener to override methods of Videoview like

boolean  canPause()  
boolean  canSeekBackward()

boolean  canSeekForward()

int  getBufferPercentage()

int  getCurrentPosition()

int  getDuration()

boolean  isPlaying()

How to pause a video. For audio we use mediaController.setMediaPlayer. How we can use for video.

Basically my code for playing video is like this :

mediaController = new MediaController(activity); 
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);  
        videoView.setVideoPath(filePath);     
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        mediaController.show();
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController); 
 
And also I want to know what is the difference between  mediaController.setMediaPlayer 
(videoView); and videoView.setMediaController(mediaController). 
Can Anyone help me in sorting out thi issue.  
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cant. You might have to write your own videoview by overriding the SurfaceView and creating a MediaPlayer instance. But in this case you would have to handle many factors like video dimension, playback, buffer etc...